# Get index position from array using .each()

Tags: jquery

How do I retrieve the index position of each element?:

```
$(myArray).each(function() {
 console.log( ...this.indexOf()?.... )
}
```

Comment: FYI `.each()` should be used only for jQuery object relative to DOM nodes, here you should use: `$.each(myArray, function(index){console.log(index);})`

Answer (score 3):

Read the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). The first argument to your callback is the index.

So:

```
$(myArray).each(function(index,item) {
    console.log(index);
});
```

Side note: [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) takes it's arguments in the opposite order (item first, then index) which, IMHO, feels more natural. I have no idea why jQuery ended up putting the arguments that way around.

Answer (score 2):

You will get the index of the current item as the first argument to the callback function of [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
$(myArray).each(function(i) {
    console.log(i);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2nrkZ/)

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.each](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$(myArray).each(function(index, value) {
 console.log(index);
}
```